# Perference Dialog

Tags: android

I created a  Preference activity

And I create a ListPreference

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="my_list"
        android:title="@string/my_list_label"
        android:entries="@array/my_list_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/my_list_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_size_limit"
    />
```

My question is when I click the ListPreferene, it pops up a dialog, and when I click an entry that, why the onResume() or onCreate() method of my Preference activity is not called?

Thank you.

Comment: post your activity code, its easy to understand for us.

Comment: He did but just forgot to format it properly. I fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks), see [onPause()'s description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29).  This normal and any Dialog will do this, if the UI also becomes completely obscured then `onStop` will be called too.